# Trying to run an executable from a Node script

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run an executable from a node script. Can anyone tell me where this is going wrong?

Relevant code:

```
const exec = require('child_process').execFile;
/**
 * Function to execute exe
 * @param {string} fileName The name of the executable file to run.
 * @param {string[]} params List of string arguments.
 * @param {string} path Current working directory of the child process.
 */
 function execute(fileName, params, path) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(fileName, params, { cwd: path }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
                console.log(fileName, params, path);
                reject(err);
            }
            else resolve(data);
        });

    });
    return promise;
}

function resetVPN() {
    execute("NordVPN.exe",["-c","-g",'"United States"'],"C:\\Program Files\\NordVPN\\");
}
```

resetVPN is returning "command failed"

```
PS C:\Users\Michael\Documents\SourceCode\LeadScraper> node test.js
Command failed: NordVPN.exe -c -g "United States"

NordVPN.exe [ '-c', '-g', '"United States"' ] C:\Program Files\NordVPN\
node:internal/errors:841
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Command failed: NordVPN.exe -c -g "United States"

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
  code: 2,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'NordVPN.exe -c -g "United States"'
}
```

The command 'NordVPN.exe -c -g "United States"' works fine from a regular command prompt, and from within powershell now.  Any tips?

Comment: Does it work when you execute the command from the terminal?

Comment: Yes. It works fine from the command prompt.  In powershell (I'm doing this through visual studio code), it returns a message about trusted apps.  I'm about to try to run it through the dos box and see if it matters.

Comment: So now I've added the executable path to my path variable, and the command executes both on the command line and in powershell, but it still fails in my script. :(

Comment: I never got this to work.  What I ended up doing was creating a batch file and then ran the batch file with a regular exec call from node.... that worked.  Disappointed.

Comment: Figure out what the exit code 2 means.